# Static variables in jmeter

Tags: java, jmeter

I have the following question for Jmeter. Request your help.

- Across my test plan(within the same thread group) I have created multiple HTTP requests which in turn uses multiple Java sampler to process the information and puts it into a certain user defined variable which finally goes into these HTTP requests body. All these java samplers are classes, while some of them has static variables which I have used as counters and also to hold some request specific data. All these classes are jar files which I have placed inside the lib\ext folder of Jmeter.

I would like to know w.r.t static variables/classes in the sampler I have used & assuming One loop inside a thread group is termed as one run

- Will the static variables populated in run-1 be present for run-2 and
  further runs as well since it is static?
- Since these runs are going    to be concurrent, will the static
  values get messed up?

Many thanks.

Comment: Thanks. I just logged in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answers are:

- Yes
- Yes

2 solutions:

1/ In a Setup Thread Group call, use a Beanshell to reset your static variables

2/ Synhronize access to static variables